# QT complains regarding GL library

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, qt

Trying to build widget GUI application on QT on 32 bit Ubuntu. Qt shows error during build;

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to fix this problem? What should be installed in general before I use QT in fresh Ubuntu installation?

Comment: What version of QT, and how did you install it? `libGL` would usually be provided by installing a suitable OpenGL development package (such as `libgl1-mesa-dev`) on your system

Comment: `aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dev` helped. Have no reason it was missing Ready to accept like answer. QT installed by downloading and run qt online install tool.

Comment: @vico libGL is nothing to do with Qt. Therefore, it would not be installed as part of the Qt install process.